# Как очистить массив от одинаковых значений? [PHP]

Tags: php, массивы

Есть список тегов товаров. Так как теги повторяются, то соответственно в массиве тег может быть столько раз, сколько раз он входит в товары.

Все теги получены вот так:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product_id = $product['product_id'];
        $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

        if ($product_info['tag']) {
            $tags = explode(',', $product_info['tag']);

            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $input = trim($tag);
                $input2 .= $input . ',';
            }
                print_r( $input2 );
        }
}
```

В результате все значения в строке через запятую.

1) как убрать из списка повторяющиеся значения (т.е. оставить только уникальные теги)?

2) как вывести значения каждого уникального тега отдельно?

---

Вопрос решён, спасибо Ипатьев. Окончательный вариант

```
$all_tags = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']);

    if ($product_info['tag']) {
        $tags = explode(',', $product_info['tag']);

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $all_tags[trim($tag)] = trim($tag);
        }
    }
}

$all_tags = array_values($all_tags);

foreach ($all_tags as $uniqtag) {
    echo $uniqtag  . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Не понятно что за данные у вас в итоге получаются. Хотя бы пример привели. А для уникальности существует `array_unique`

Comment: Пример такой. В товаре теги записываются в одну строчку через запятую.
Товар 1 имеет теги: носки, носки женские.
Товар 2 имеет теги: носки, носки мужские.
Собирая теги всех товаров имеем: носки, носки женские, носки, носки мужские.
Тег "носки" повторяется. Задача оставить тег "носки" один раз, убрав повторы.
P.S. array_unique не понадобился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если для одного продукта, то так:

```
$tags = explode(',', $product_info['tag']);
$tags = array_map('trim', $tags);
$tags = array_unique($tags);
```

А если для всех - то так:

```
$all_tags = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']);
    $tags = explode(',', $product_info['tag']);
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $all_tags[trim($tag)] = 1;
    }
}
$all_tags = array_values($all_tags);
```

Добавление тегов ключами, а не значениями, сразу будет обеспечивать уникальность.

Но по-хорошему trim() и explode() здесь лишние. trim() надо делать перед записью в БД, а модель должна возвращать теги сразу в виде массива.